# Traceback (most recent call last): Python

Tags: python, eclipse, azure

When I am trying to run my python code in eclipse I am getting this error:

[image: Traceback request error]

Here is my code:

```
"""
Module Name:  deviceManager.py
Project:      IoTHubRestSample
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

Using [Device Indentities REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt548489.aspx) to create a new device identity, retrieve a device identity, and list device identities.

This source is subject to the Microsoft Public License.
See http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/openness/licenses.aspx#MPL
All other rights reserved.

THIS CODE AND INFORMATION IS PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, 
EITHER EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE IMPLIED 
WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND/OR FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
"""

import base64
import hmac
import hashlib
import time
import requests
import urllib

class DeviceManager:
    API_VERSION = '2016-02-03'
    TOKEN_VALID_SECS = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
    TOKEN_FORMAT = 'SharedAccessSignature sr=%s&sig=%s&se=%s&skn=%s'

    def __init__(self, connectionString=None):
        if connectionString != None:
            iotHost, keyName, keyValue = [sub[sub.index('=') + 1:] for sub in connectionString.split(";")]
            self.iotHost = iotHost
            self.keyName = keyName
            self.keyValue = keyValue

    def _buildExpiryOn(self):
        return '%d' % (time.time() + self.TOKEN_VALID_SECS)

    def _buildSasToken(self):
        targetUri = self.iotHost.lower()
        expiryTime = self._buildExpiryOn()
        toSign = '%s\n%s' % (targetUri, expiryTime)
        key = base64.b64decode(self.keyValue.encode('utf-8'))
        signature = urllib.quote(
            base64.b64encode(
                hmac.HMAC(key, toSign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()
                )
        ).replace('/', '%2F')
        return self.TOKEN_FORMAT % (targetUri, signature, expiryTime, self.keyName)

    def createDeviceId(self, deviceId):
        sasToken = self._buildSasToken()
        url = 'https://%s/devices/%s?api-version=%s' % (self.iotHost, deviceId, self.API_VERSION)
        body = '{deviceId: "%s"}' % deviceId
        r = requests.put(url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': sasToken}, data=body)
        return r.text, r.status_code

    def retrieveDeviceId(self, deviceId):
        sasToken = self._buildSasToken()
        url = 'https://%s/devices/%s?api-version=%s' % (self.iotHost, deviceId, self.API_VERSION)
        r = requests.get(url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': sasToken})
        return r.text, r.status_code

    def listDeviceIds(self, top=None):
        if top == None:
            top = 1000
        sasToken = self._buildSasToken()
        url = 'https://%s/devices?top=%d&api-version=%s' % (self.iotHost, top, self.API_VERSION)
        r = requests.get(url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': sasToken})
        return r.text, r.status_code

    def deleteDeviceId(self, deviceId):
        sasToken = self._buildSasToken()
        url = 'https://%s/devices/%s?api-version=%s' % (self.iotHost, deviceId, self.API_VERSION)
        r = requests.delete(url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': sasToken, 'If-Match': '*' }) 
        # If-Match Etag, but if * is used, no need to precise the Etag of the device. The Etag of the device can be seen in the header requests.text response 
        return r.text, r.status_code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connectionString = 'HostName=<iot-hub-name>.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=<iothubowner-policy-key>'
    dm = DeviceManager(connectionString)
    deviceId='iotdevice1'
    print(dm.createDeviceId(deviceId))
    print(dm.retrieveDeviceId(deviceId))
    print(dm.listDeviceIds())
```

How to fix this?

Comment: and how is this java related? from the error it seems you are exceeding the limit of retries the requests library has. I suggest you catch the exception and sleep some time e.g. 5 secs and retry your request

Comment: Because I am using eclipse to run this code.Python is integrated with it. I tried debugging but unable to find this error.

Can you please try to go through the program code and error screenshot attached and suggest me the solution?

Comment: as what i have mentioned, try to catch the exception, put the call to line 55 inside a try-except and sleep for some time, after that call the same method again and see if it will go through

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add you code directly to the question (create a [mcve]) instead of linking to a website.

Comment: This error usually means that the end point did not respond. You sure the address is correct? It will retry multiple times in case its a temporary error then throw this error. That host name in the stack trade looks very weird. It looks a bit like you didn't escape some characters?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your linking code is an Azure code sample written by me, which comes from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-hub-python-get-started/blob/master/Python/service/deviceManager.py) and its introduction at [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/iot-hub-python-get-started/). According to your error screenshot, I see the code `connectionString = 'HostName=<iot-hub-name>.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=<iothubowner-policy-key>'` was not changed. Please follow the offical tutorial [`Create an IoT hub using the Azure portal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-create-through-portal) to create an IoTHub if you had not, and copy your IoT hub name & key(as below) instead of `<iot-hub-name>` & `<iothubowner-policy-key>`.

[image]